# Calculating expectation, infinite fair coins tosses

Tags: probability, expectation

Let's say I am tossing an infinite amount of fair coins independently (one side is $H$, and one side is $T$).

What's the expectation of the number of tosses until I see two following coins such that the first is $H$ and the second is $T$?

Comment: Does "Following coins" mean "consecutive coins"?

Comment: Hint: First you are waiting for the first H to occur (T is a failure and H is a succes). After that you are waiting for the first T to occur (H is a failure and T is a succes). The predecessor of this T is necessarily an H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the law of total expectation to solve this question.

$$\mathbb E[\text{#number of tosses}] = P(\text{H throws first})*\mathbb E[\text{T is thrown}+1] + P(\text{T throws first})*\mathbb E[\text{#number of tosses} +1]$$.

Note that the "$+1$" is because of the "turn wasted". The probabiliies we get $H$ or $T$ at the first turn is $0.5$ for each, and the expectation of $T$ is thrown is geometric with $p=0.5$. If we get $T$ at the first turn we need to "start all over again" (but remember we already "wasted" one turn).

Therefore:

(Let us write $\mathbb E[\text{#number of tosses}] = X$)

$$X = 0.5 * (2+1) + 0.5(X + 1)$$
$$ X = 1.5 + 0.5X + 0.5$$
$$0.5X = 2$$
$$ X=4$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, for an unfair coin with $P(H)=p$ and $P(T)=q=1-p$  The expected time for getting the sequence "HT" is
$$
\mathbb{E}\{\tau(HT)\} = \frac1{pq}
$$

But, this is the trivial result.  Try the same for "HH" (or "TT") sequences and you'll get surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of flips required to observe two consecutive coins $HT$. For any non-negative integer $k$, $X>k$ iff the first $k$ tosses are: $j$ $T$s and then $k-j$ $H$s with $j=0,1,2,\dots,k$. Hence 
$$P(X>k)=\frac{k+1}{2^k}$$
which implies that
$$E(X)=\sum_{k\geq 0}P(X>k)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{k+1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^2}=4.$$